# Two conics have exactly one intersection point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

We have two conics $Q_1,Q_2$ on $\mathbb{P}_2$ over some algebraically closed field. Also $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are supposed to be smooth.
 I've just discovered Bezout's theorem, which states that two algebraic curves with degrees $m$ and $k$ have exactly $km$ intersection points (of course some of them can be the same). So, I'd like to build some examples when two conics have exactly $1,2,3$ and $4$ distinct intersection points. All cases but not the $1$st are quite easy. For example, $q_1(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z^2$ and $q_2(x,y,x)=x^2+2y^2-z^2$ are two polynomials which define smooth conics on $\mathbb{P}_2$ and they have exactly $2$ intersection points $(1:0:1)$ and $(1:0:-1)$. When we need three or four points, there are similar examples. But what about $1$ point? I cannot build an example. Is it possible? I'd like to note that conics are smooth.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The conics $x^2-yz=0$ and $x^2+z^2-yz=0$ are smooth (in all characteristics) and intersect only in one point, namely $[0:1:0]$.

Comment: What is the method to finding the intersection? you follow the classic way?

Comment: @Bill:  For  $z=1$  you must solve $x^2-y=0, x^2+1-y=0$ (no solution) and for $z=0$ you must solve $z=0, x^2=0$ whose only solution is $[0:1:0]$ .

Comment: Thank you so much, I have two conics in $\mathbb{P]^2$, is there anyway to find the intersection of the conics by their symmetric matrices?

Answer (score 1):

Take any two pairs of intersecting lines with different slope: $x^2+a_1y^2=0$ and $x^2+a_2y^2=0$ for $a_1 \neq a_2$. They only cross at the origin $(0:0:1)$

Also, take the double y axis $x^2=0$ and the double x axis $y^2=0$ (or any pair of double-lines with different slopes), which again only cross at the origin.

Comment: Dear rewritten, your conics are not smooth.

Comment: You are completely right.